# Passed the variable through javascript but not getting it in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am passing my variable throught an AJAX request in javascript but not getting it in my php file. NOt sure where i am going wrong.?

JS code

```
var build = {
m_count : (document.getElementById('count').value),
}
$.ajax({
    data: build,
    type: "POST",
    url: "tabs.php",});
```

PHP code

```
<?php

$module_c = $_POST['data'];
echo $module_c;
?>
```

Comment: var_dump or print_r are your friends.  i.e.:  var_dump($_POST);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the data by the name of the variable you want to get, which is m_count.

```
<?php
    $module_c = $_POST['m_count'];
    echo $module_c;
?>
```

EDIT:

Like suggested in the comments, change your JavaScript code to:

```
var build = {
    m_count : (document.getElementById('count').value)
}

$.ajax({
    data: build,
    type: "POST",
    url: "tabs.php",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: @veenu this is a right answer but you still need to use ajax `success` or `.done()` callback function

Comment: Complete your answer by add `success` or `.done()` and alert the returned data

Comment: i am fairly new to this. can you please tell how to use success callback function

Comment: @veenu 1st- always keep eyes on console for errors .. 2nd- for everything you use something like `{ value1 : value1, value2 :value }`  no need for last `,` before  closing `}` you may got a syntax error `,` .. so always remove the last `,` comma before closing `}` .. that mean for `m_count : (document.getElementById('count').value),` no need for the last `,` remove it

Comment: @Andrey Thanks man. Seems like i am very close. In the console i am getting this. Array
(
    [m_count] => 12
). Which is the value i want but not getting on screen by echo"$module_c");

Comment: @veenu Good. To put stuff on the screen you'd usually set the HTML div or element you want with the value you got back from the php code. Like, when you have a div with id "my-div" in your HTML code you could do `$('#my-div').append(data);` in your success function.

Comment: @AndreyRK console.log(data); in success function returning my whole php file. But i just need value of m_count

Comment: @veenu That seems like a problem with your web server. This usually happens when you're not running the web page in a server.

Comment: Thanks Andrey but i dont think so beacause every other file is okay. no server issue. Looks like $_POST is a associative ARRAY and to print that echo $module_c; is not enough. BUt i dont know how to print associative array in php

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
   <?php
        $module_c = $_POST['m_count'];
        echo $module_c;
    ?>
```

JS:

```
var build = {
    m_count : (document.getElementById('count').value),
}

$.ajax({
        url: 'php/server.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: build,
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
            // JSON.parse turns a string of JSON text into a Javascript object.
            var message = JSON.parse(msg);
            alert(message);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.log("Error: "+err);

    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("Complete");
    })
```

;